# I am getting a TypeError: Not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am new to programming and hopefully this is just a simple fix. Everything is working except for when I am trying to find the number of `N`'s in the sequences. This is the code I am using:

```
from __future__ import division

print "Sequence Information"

f = open('**,fasta','r')

while True:
    seqId = f.readline()

    #Check if there are still lines
    if not seqId: break

    seqId = seqId.strip()[1:]
    seq = f.readline()
    # Find the %GC
    gcPercent = (( seq.count('G') + seq.count('g') + seq.count('c') + seq.count('C') ) / (len( seq )) *100)

    N = (seq.count('N') + 1)

    print "%s\t%d\t%.4f" % (seqId, len( seq ), gcPercent, N)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "length", line 20, in <module>
    print "%s\t%d\t%.4f" % (seqId, len( seq ), gcPercent, N)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How do I make it so I can add the value of `N` to the 4th column?

Comment: Why not add another `\t%d` then?

Comment: you have 3 `%` in string but 4 value at following !

Answer (score 2):

You gave four arguments to `%` but only have three format fields:

```
print "%s\t%d\t%.4f" % (seqId, len( seq ), gcPercent, N)
#      ^1  ^2  ^3       ^1     ^2          ^3         ^4
```

Python requires you to have one format field per argument like so:

```
print "%s\t%d\t%.4f\t%d" % (seqId, len( seq ), gcPercent, N)
```

Of course, modern Python code should be using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead:

```
print "{}\t{}\t{:.4f}\t{}".format(seqId, len(seq), gcPercent, N)
```